# How to create a child theme in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to create a child theme so I can customize the parent theme but it is not working what-so-ever. I did everything I can think of:

1. created a folder for my child theme under `wp-content/themes`
2. created a `style.css` stylesheet and saved it in the child theme folder:

   ```
   /*
   Theme Name:   Twenty Thirteen Child Theme
   Description:  Twenty Thirteen Child Theme
   Author:       Ashley
   Template:     twentythirteen
   Version:      1.0.0
   */
   ```
3. and I went to Appearance > Themes in WordPress but no child theme showed up. I have tried it multiple times and don't know what to do.

Comment: [How to Create a Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: Is there any error showing in appearance->themes screen?

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty good tutorial here:
https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial. I've taken a snippet from it for the `style.css` file, and substituted bits with your info:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Thirteen Child Theme
 Description:  Twenty Thirteen Child Theme
 Author:       Ashley
 Template:     twentythirteen
 Version:      1.0.0
*/

@import url("../twentythirteen/style.css");

/* =Theme customization starts here
------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Be sure to link properly to the TwentyThirteen theme's `style.css` file (via `@import`); make sure you're using the right path. Then you can proceed as normal by visiting "Appearance > Themes".

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple [**article**](https://dedevop.com/wordpress-child-theme/)

- create child theme directory
- create styles.css
- create functions.php