# How to edit an already existing Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, docker, themes

I know it can be a very dummy question but I'm trying to figure out how I can develop and make changes in an already existing wordpress page (write new code, etc)? Before the changes go online, I must be able to save it somehow and I also need approval from its owner.
What is the best practice for it? It has some paid plugins also, I was thinking that I should create a parallel wordpress site exporting everything from the existing one and work locally.. how does it sound? Any suggestions?

I work on mac and use Docker.
Many thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: You should create a child theme to make changes to the main theme, but note that themes and plugins are separate and a theme does not include the sites plugins. I think you might be mixing up 2 questions here - it sounds like you want to change the theme *and* be able to makes changes to the appearance or functionality that some of the plugins add. Either way, it is always better to have a separate development environment that to work on the actual site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a child theme in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923879/how-to-create-a-child-theme-in-wordpress)

Comment: From your comment on the answer below, changing the theme is only a tiny part of what you want to do as I suspected. Menus, plugins etc are part of the site, not the theme, so you are really settingup a new site with some of the same elements. You will need to set up a new installation of WP. You can create a copy of the existing site to start with if it helps take a look at [this answer about how to create a copy of an existing site on another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62787699/building-a-new-website-without-affecting-the-current-website-wordpress-until-f/62789135#62789135)

Comment: yes, that is what i thought! That I probably I would need to create a parallel developing environment for this website. My only remaining question now is: since there are some paid plugins on the website (they impact a lot the functionality), how will i be able to have them also? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read on Wordpress Developers relating to Child Themes. Tou can get started here - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

This will allow you to activate a child theme over a normal theme and any changes you make to its functions.php will not be overridden when the parent theme updates.

You will just need to maintain the code incase major updates are undertaken on the parent theme.

Comment: Mmm, is it eough only using the child theme? because Im not gonna change only its style but Ill also change for instance the menu (replace for a new one), etc