# I'm facing an issue with the navigation menu on my website

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm facing an issue with the Hamburger Menu in the Primary Menu of my website. It works everywhere correctly, but when you're in a blog post or any single post, the pages listed there don't work, and a black hover appears on the top of the pages. Please just figure out what is the root of the error.

You can check the attached video file to see the issue.
https://www.screencast.com/t/MgB2tSvs

Please someone tell me where exactly should I put the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to hide this overlay:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px)
html.g1-off-outside.g1-off-global-desktop .g1-canvas-overlay {
    display: none;
}
```

Or you can increase the z-index of your menu:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px)
html.g1-off-outside.g1-off-global-desktop .g1-canvas {
    width: 320px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 998;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, Mr. Ken Lee & Thomas Liberato, for your assistance. Can you assist me further where exactly should I add the code you've provided, I'm not so familiar with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the z-index number of your left hand side navigation menu so that it is larger than the top navigation portion of the blog page

Comment: Hi, Thank you, Mr Ken Lee & Thomas Liberato, for your assistance. Can you assist me further where exactly should I add the code you've provided, I'm not so familiar with CSS.

Comment: You should create a child theme and write this CSS code in style.css.

More informations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923879/how-to-create-a-child-theme-in-wordpress

Comment: Dear Thomas, I've added the code you've provided in the child theme's style.css, but the issue is still there. Any alternative to get rid of this issue?